# Spring batch - configure number of threads

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have configured a `TaskExecutor` with `maxPoolSize` 1 and `throttleLimit` 1 what I see is its running 2 threads. I want to use my spring batch app as single threaded at the moment and configure this capability by just increasing the number of threads in my properties file later if needed. The question is why it would run 2 threads when I have mentioned the pool size and throttle limit as 1.

how did I find it?

I am setting

```
.throttleLimit(1)
```

and

```
asyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(1);
```

I am naming my `TaskExecutor` as `"poller_batch_thread"` and in the read() method I am printing the names of threads starting with `"poller_"` and this is what I see in logs:

```
2019-01-21 10:08:50 INFO  m.d.s.a.b.reader.PortalMessageReader - Portal Message Read by Thread id 115 - Thread name: poller_batch_thread115
2019-01-21 10:08:50 INFO  m.d.s.a.b.reader.PortalMessageReader - Portal Message Read by Thread id 116 - Thread name: poller_batch_thread116
```

Comment: Provide more details of how you found that it is running 2 threads.

Comment: How did you conclude that it is running two threads? Are you sure these two threads are not the sum of the main thread + the (single) thread of the pool?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

As asked before, i'm wondering if it's not the main thread + the thread of the pool.
You are using a Task Executor, so Spring Batch is maybe switching to Master / Slave mode.
I recommand you to do some debug and identifiy what implementation of Tasklet is used and watch the "execute" method so you get and idea of what is done "behind the scene" :).

Hope it helps.